# Make SVG element transparent (like a mask)

Tags: svg

How can I use the polygon as a mask, which will make the area in the circle transparent?
I cannot manage it

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    <polygon points="20,30 25,20 80,40 80,60 25,80, 20,70 70,50"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Masks are quite simple.  They are described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#Masking

In your case, it is just a matter of adding a few lines.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" mask="url(#hole)"/>
        
   <mask id="hole">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="white"/>
      <polygon points="20,30 25,20 80,40 80,60 25,80, 20,70 70,50" fill="black"/>
   </mask>
</svg>
```

In the mask definition, we have to add a white rectangle the size of the circle to make the `<circle>` visible (white means opaque), and we make the `<polygon>` black (transparent) to create the hole.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/utjLL/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say try using [Inkscape](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkscape/) to make an SVG file, draw your items on each other, select them both and use the `Path->Exclusion` menu to do so.  Save your file and then you can look at the code of the `.svg` file to see what it did.